# Google Analytics with R

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am new to Google analytics API.....I authenticated my application in R using code:

```
library(RGoogleAnalytics)  
client.id <- "**************.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client.secret <- "**********************"
token <- Auth(client.id, client.secret)
save(token,file="./token_file")
ValidateToken(token)
```

I am figuring out what we need to enter in the below credentials:

```
query.list <- Init(start.date = "2011-11-28", 
    end.date = "2014-12-04", 
    dimensions = "ga:date,ga:pagePath,ga:hour,ga:medium", 
    metrics = "ga:sessions,ga:pageviews", 
    max.results = 10000, sort = "-ga:date", table.id = "ga:33093633")
```

Where can I find dimensions, metrics, sort, table.id

My eventual goal is to pull the text from "https://plus.google.com/105253676673287651806/posts"

Please do assist me in this....

Comment: I typically use [this site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=user,session)

Comment: Have you read the documentation? All of the things you're asking for are marked "optional", with the exception of table.id, where the library documentation explicitly states "Profile ID of the form ga:XXXXX where XXXXX is the Analytics View (Profile) ID of for which the query will retrieve the data. The View ID can be found under View Settings by navigating to the Admin Tab under your Google Analytics Profile"

Comment: There are a few Google Analytics R tutorials here http://markedmondson.me/tag/r   But I do not understand that you have a goal to pull text from a Google+ user which has nothing to do with Google Analytics.

Comment: @DaImTo then how can I pull the data of a specific google+ user? Is there any other way?

Comment: What do you mean by data? What is it you want to see about a Google+ user?  https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Comment: @DaImTo I want to pull his posts for analysis

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/#Activities Lets you requests posts for a Google+ user. But this is a different question not at all related to what you have asked in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Analytics and R may not suit what you want to do here, as the Google+ website won't be included in the data you collect.

You may want to look at using [RVest](https://github.com/hadley/rvest) which is a URL scraper tool for R.  You could then get the information you need from any public URL into an R dataframe for you to analyse later.

Answer (score 0):

Query Explorer:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?csw=1

Dimensions and metrics:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets